# Deep Learning: Loss not going down (almost constant) while training GoogLeNet

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to fine-tune GoogLeNet in caffe.

DataSet: Images from 8 localities in New York (approx 2500 images in Training data from each of these 8 classes)
So, in this fine-grained classification, i wanted the analyze AlexNet and GoogLenet.

I retrained only last 2 FC layers of AlexNet and got around 70% Test accuracy.
However, on GoogLeNet i am consistently getting around 20-30% train accuracy while finetuning. The loss stays almost constant around 2. Its barely going down.

I have played around all the hyperparameters?

I have just changed the last FC layers, in both these networks.
Is this expected behavior? Shouldn't GoogLeNet give better results?
Do i need to tweak something else in GoogLeNet?